# Django - join between different models without foreign key

Tags: sql, django, django-models

Imagine I have two simple models (it's not really what I have but this will do):

```
Class Person(models.Model):
    person_id = models.TextField()
    name = models.TextField()
    #...some other fields

Class Pet(models.Model):
    person_id = models.TextField()
    pet_name = models.TextField()
    species = models.TextField()
    #...even more fields
```

Here's the key difference between this example and some other questions I read about: my models don't enforce a foreign key, so I can't use `select_related()`

I need to create a view that shows a join between two querysets in each one. So, let's imagine I want a view with all owners named John with a dog.

```
# a first filter
person_query = Person.objects.filter(name__startswith="John")
# a second filter
pet_query = Pet.objects.filter(species="Dog")
# the sum of the two
magic_join_that_i_cant_find_and_possibly_doesnt_exist = join(person_query.person_id, pet_query.person_id)
```

Now, can I join those two very very simple querysets with any function?

Or should I use raw?

```
SELECT p.person_id, p.name, a.pet_name, a.species
FROM person p 
LEFT JOIN pet a ON 
    p.person_id = a.person_id AND
    a.species = 'Dog' AND
    p.name LIKE 'John%'
```

Is this query ok? Damn, I'm not sure anymore... that's my issue with queries. Everything is all at once. But consecutive queries seem so simple...

If I reference in my model class a "foreign key" (for `select_related()` use), will it be enforced in the database after the migration? (I need that it DOESN'T happen)

Comment: You should explain why you don't use foreign keys, and change your models so that you do. Using TextFields (ie blobs) for all fields is inefficient and unnecessary.

Comment: Well, it is a characteristic of the problem, it is black box. That's how the database is already and I'm not supposed to mess with the design (although I could). Either way, the DB has OLAP characteristics, so triggers and constraints aren't optimal. Textfield is how the legacy db integration function mapped it.

Comment: Well, you don't have to believe the output of inspectdb - it even says that you need to edit it. If a field is a representation of an ID in another model, it's a foreign key.

Comment: Does `person_id` contain an integer value? Then just try to make a foreign key in Django despite the `TextField`. Maybe it just works...

Comment: But, Daniel, I'll ask again what's at the end: if I write in models.py that this and this other field are foreign, when I migrate, will this constraints be written in the database?

Answer (score 6):

Make a models.ForeignKey but use `db_constraint=False`.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.db_constraint

Also, if this model is `managed=False`, ie it is a legacy db table and you're not using Django migrations, the constraint won't ever be made in the first place and it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a FK in the model, Django will create a constraint on migration, so you want to avoid that in your case.

I don't think there is a way to join in the database in Django if you don't declare the field to join as a foreign key. The only thing you can do is to do the join in Python, which might or might not be OK. Think that `prefetch_related` does precisely this.

The code would be something like:

```
person_query = Person.objects.filter(name__startswith="John")
person_ids = [person.id for person in person_query]
pet_query = Pet.objects.filter(species="Dog", person_id__in=person_ids).order_by('person_id')
pets_by_person_id = {person_id: pet_group for person_id, pet_group in itertools.groupby(pet_query, lambda pet: pet.person_id)}

# Now everytime you need the pets for a certain person
pets_by_person_id(person.id)

# You can also set it in all objects for easy retrieval
for person in person_query:
    person.pets = pets_by_person_id(person.id)
```

The code might not be 100% accurate, but you get the idea I hope.

Comment: I did find a website using a similar approach. Actually, it's from there that I went with the "pet" "owner" models example, but it wasn't really clear for me. There is still quite some heavy machine-use if there are a lot of records, aren't there? If I do a get inside a for it will hit the db an insane ammount of times. If I do this, all the variables will be stored in RAM? Is it right?

Comment: Using this approach you only hit the database once per model, so in this case its 2 times. And yes, all records would be stored in memory - but you can use `queryset.only(*fields)` and `queryset.values(*fields)` to mitigate this to a great extent probably. What you cannot avoid with this approach is the join in Python, which might be an issue but only when you are dealing with way many records probably.

Comment: For now I went the easy way and wrote a `get` inside a `for`. Terrible option, I know. It does seem a little slow. I will next try your way and see which one takes less time. Thank you.